# React Hooks Refs

Tags: reactjs

So I decidet to rewrite my React Class Component into React Hook Component,
And in my Class Component I did

```
<canvas ref='canvas'></canvas>
```

This approach didn't work anymore. How should I use refs then? In documentation only said that refs are still work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With hooks you can use the `useRef` hook.

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

look at the `useRef` docs here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: How do we pass this up to a class?

Comment: I see how this works when the referenced DOM element is used after a button click. What about when you need to update `someRef.current` in a `useEffect` function? It looks like the effect is being called before the DOM is drawn, and it crashes. This is all very confusing...

Answer (score 12):

In case you would like to use refs inside a map function:

```
export default () => {
    const items = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango'];

    // 1) create an array of refs
    const itemRefs = useRef(items.map(() => React.createRef()));

    useEffect(() => {
        // 3) access a ref, for example 0
        itemRefs.current[0].current.focus()
    }, []);

    return (
        <ul>
            {items.map((item, i) => (
                // 2) attach ref to each item
                <li key={item} ref={itemRefs.current[i]}>{item}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Showing just one example of how it worked for me in a non-verbose way in React Native.

```
export function Screen() {

   /*
    * Call function for example of access to the component, 
    * being able to access calls to its functions.
    */
    const callRef = () => {
       testeRef.example();
    };

    return (
       <CustomComponent ref={(e) => testRef = e}></CustomComponent>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By referring the input from the user in function hooks use `useref()`.

```
function Canvas(){
  const firstNameRef=useref(null);
  const [firstName, setFirstName]=useState(); 
  const submitevent =()=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     setFirstName(firstNameRef.current.value);
  }
  return(
      <form>
        <input value={firstName} ref={firstNameRef}/>
        <button onClick={submitevent}>submit</button>
      </form>
  )
}
```

It will helps you for the ref hooks:)